# Can't click on href element in selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I need a help clicking on this element:

```
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-left ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tabs-3" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true">
    <a href="#tabs-3" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-3">Prevent propagation</a>
</li>
<!-- edit: missing a li element here? -->
    <a href="#tabs-3" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-3">Prevent propagation</a>
</li>
```

I have tried `Driver.FindElement().Click;` By `Xpath,` `className`, `Link` and `PartialLinkText`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//li[contains(., 'Prevent propagation')]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the link you're trying to navigate is a relative one to a #tabs-3 element. You can try to just execute `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("URL/#tabs-3");`

It's hard to say why your FindElement doesn't work without seeing what is the exact HTML and what exactly you tried to use in your By classes.

According to the above code, this should work:

`var list = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("ui-tabs-anchor"));`

Notice that because you have multiple web elements with that class name, you should get a list of web elements back - access any of the list elements to actually click it (list[0].Click(), for example).

Answer (score 0):

Try to wait some time until link appears in `DOM` and became clickable:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.LinkText("Prevent propagation"))).Click();
```